# Create Rails SQL Function + PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-function

I want to know the correct syntax for writing down function in rails.
This needs to accept parameters.

Code I have managed is:

```
    def up
    self.connection.execute %Q( CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION business_objective_function RETURNS INT AS $$
        BEGIN
            RETURN 1;
        END
     )
end
```

While running migration : syntax error at or near "RETURNS"